# Selecting MIN and MAX at the same time while GROUPING on another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been stuck with the following problem for several days now.
My base table looks something like this:

```
departure; departure_date; destination; entered_on

FRA; 2015-10-01; SIN; 2015-09-18 06:24:31

SIN; 2015-10-02; SYD; 2015-09-18 06:24:31

FRA; 2015-10-01; HKG; 2015-09-18 06:28:44  

HKG; 2015-10-04; SYD; 2015-09-18 06:28:44  

SYD; 2015-10-06; LAX; 2015-09-18 06:28:44
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the departure for the mininum departure date and the destination for the maximum departure date, grouped by the "entered_on" date.
So the result would look like:

```
departure; destination; entered_on

FRA; SYD; 2015-09-18 06:24:31

FRA; LAX; 2015-09-18 06:28:44
```

I've tried countless variants of subqueries which all failed.
Mostly I did something like:

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT departure 
   FROM table 
   WHERE departure_date = (SELECT MAX(departure_date) FROM table)
  ) AS maxdep 
FROM `table`
```

but this doesn't give me the desired result.
Is this even possible or am I on the wrong track here?

OK I've added the structure to fiddle: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2766/2)

So this means the originally posted table is created via a subquery.

Comment: Out of countless variants of subqueries you tried add one here else you are not going to get help

Comment: thanks for the hint, own example added :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.departure ORDER BY departure_date), ",", "1") AS departure,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.destination ORDER BY departure_date DESC), ",", "-1") AS destination,
  t.entered_on
FROM tableName AS t
GROUP BY t.entered_on
```

> **Edit 1:** Added `order by` within `group concat` as pointed out by **@dnoeth** in
>   comments.

Here is the [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/932cb/3).

> **Edit 2:** the original table I posted was created via: SELECT *, (SELECT created_on FROM created WHERE created.flight_id=flights.id) AS
>   created_on FROM flights so the created_on column was not orignially
>   part of the table. I tried putting this whole query in subquery after
>   your "FROM"

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(f.departure ORDER BY f.departure_date ), ",", 1) AS departure,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(f.destination ORDER BY f.departure_date DESC), ",", 1) AS destination,
  c.created_on
FROM flights AS f
  INNER JOIN created AS c ON f.id = c.flight_id
GROUP BY c.created_on
```

Here is the [**New FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a6a2/1).

Comment: This depends on the order of rows within the source table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/932cb/1 You need to add `ORDER BY` to `GROUP_CONCAT`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/932cb/3

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your fiddle example works, but not in my case, though. It's probably due to the fact that the original table I posted was created via: SELECT *,
(SELECT created_on FROM created WHERE created.flight_id=flights.id) AS created_on
FROM `flights`     so the created_on column was not orignially part of the table. I tried putting this whole query in subquery after your "FROM", to no avail :(

Comment: @user5355646 Better update your question and all tables involved with some sample data or create a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: ok thanks, fiddle link is added. Now, when I add this query as a subquery into the "FROM" part of your suggestion, it's giving me wrong results.

Comment: thanks a bunch! Joining the other table instead of including it via subquery did the trick. Out of curiosity: I always thought in cases like this both ways would work, but that doesn't seem to be the case? Or did I just implement the subquery wrong?

Comment: @user5355646 Subquery will also work. You might have implemented it wrong. Check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a6a2/2).

Comment: You are right, I must have done it wrong, even though I had been trying to get this working forever, now I don't even know what exactly it is that was wrong. Anyway, thank you so much for you help! This was my first experience on this forum and I must say I'm highly impressed by the quick and precise answers. Apologies if I'm not using the correct formats and such yet, still learning :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not really clear to me the purpose of your query, but you can start with a group by query:

```
SELECT
  entered_on,
  MIN(departure_date) AS min_date,
  MAX(departure_date) AS max_date
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  entered_on
```

Then you can just join the result of this query back with your table twice, using two different aliases:

```
SELECT
  t1.departure,
  t2.destination,
  d.entered_on
FROM (
  SELECT
    entered_on,
    MIN(departure_date) AS min_date,
    MAX(departure_date) AS max_date
  FROM
    yourtable
  GROUP BY
    entered_on
  ) AS d INNER JOIN yourtable t1
  ON d.entered_on = t1.entered_on AND d.min_date = t1.departure_date
  INNER JOIN yourtable t2
  ON d.entered_on = t2.entered_on AND d.max_date = t2.departure_date
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53a88/2).

Answer (score 1):

In most other DBMSes this would be a simple `FIRST_VALUE(departure) OVER (PARTITION BY entered_on ORDER BY departure_date` and a similar `LAST_VALUE` for the destination, but MySQL doesn't support those Windowed Aggregate Functions.

You might use an old trick: Concat the 2nd column to the 1st column

```
select *,
   concat(departure_date, departure),
   concat(departure_date, destination)
from tab;
```

And then do a MAX/MIN on the combined column, finally extract the 2nd column using a SUBSTRING:

```
select entered_on,
   substring(min(concat(departure_date, departure)) from 11),
   substring(max(concat(departure_date, destination)) from 11)
from tab
group by entered_on
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69890/2)